# Rails cancan gem won't authorize only new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cancan

Using cancan i'm not able to create new record. I have tired to read from documentation but i can't find any help for this.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.nil?
        can :read, Branch
        can :read, Leaf
      elsif user.role? "admin"
        can :manage, :all
      else
        can :manage, Branch, :user_id => user.id
        can :manage, Leaf, :branch => { :user_id => user.id }

        # Also can read all.
        can :read, :all
    end
  end
```

Controller:

before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]

```
  def new
    @branch = Branch.new
    authorize! :new, @branch, :message => 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @branch }
      end
  end

  def create
    @branch = Branch.new(branch_params)
    authorize! :create, @branch, :message => 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'

    respond_to do |format|
      if @branch.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_branches_path(current_user.username), notice: 'Branch was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new'}
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing you are on rails 4, which by default uses strong parameters, it doesn't play nicely with CanCan. Its outlined in this [blog](http://blog.houen.net/cancan-strong-parameters/). Try [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) which is the continuation of the dead CanCan project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to change but still only :new action is not working.

Comment: me too, i tried to change it from the above samples, it really doesnt work i dont know why.